# Remote Interpreter DataSpell

Tags: interpreter, remote-server, dataspell

I am trying to run scripts on a remote server with DataSpell, so I am trying to configure a remote interpreter.

I follow [these](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dataspell/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html?_gl=1*oe9ul1*_ga*NTgwMjY1NTA4LjE2NDkxNzc0Mzk.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY4NTYzMzE2OC44OS4xLjE2ODU2MzQ5ODguNTkuMC4w&_ga=2.258116170.1145050965.1685439364-580265508.1649177439#ssh) instructions and I get the error

```
Cannot Save Settings:
SSH Python x.x.x user@IP : Python x.x.x
(path/to/interpreter) can't be used as a workspace interpreter
```

As a path to the interpreter I have used the `.../bin/python` file that is created in a virtual environment. I have tried virtual environments created both with `conda` and `venv`. I have also found [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-4483), but I cannot understand the solution clearly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Dataspell can have different interpreters for its workspace and projects or notebooks that are opened in the workspace.

I right-clicked the project folder in the Project window, and selected a remote interpreter just for the project. This is what the second source that I posted on my OP says. This works fine.

Answer (score -1):

#### To change the interpreter in your project, follow these steps:

1. Open the Project window.
2. Right-click on the project folder in the Project window.
3. From the context menu that appears, select "Interpreter"
4. A new window will open showing the current interpreter for your project.
5. Look for the option to select an SSH interpreter and choose it or “Create a new one”

That's it! The SSH interpreter should now be set up for your project, and you can start using it for your development tasks.

I hope this helps!

[image]